# Helm not adding timeout param in API server call

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

When we use helm to create Istio VirtualService or DestinationRules, it takes more than 30seconds. So we have set up a higher timeout of 5m.

Command used
`helm upgrade --install --wait --timeout 5m --v 9 helloworld ./templateDir`

However, I see that helm is not passing the new timeout value in APIserver call.
When we use kubectl to create the same, we set `--request-timeout` param for `kubectl` and everything is fine

Since it is a timeout from apiserver, is it possible to set a higher timeout value for all API server requests from helm? Is there any other workaround you can suggest for this problem ?

```
I0528 17:52:57.664992   11148 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" 'https://aaaa.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/destinationrules '
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:443] POST https://aaaa.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/destinationrules  504 Gateway Timeout in 30316 milliseconds
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:452]     Audit-Id: cba23005-b8db-47f7-8801-4c89e6447cd3
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Length: 187
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 12:23:27 GMT
I0528 17:53:27.981691   11148 request.go:1017] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s","reason":"Timeout","details":{},"code":504}
I0528 17:53:27.982759   11148 request.go:1017] Request Body: {"apiVersion":"networking.istio.io/v1beta1","kind":"VirtualService","metadata":{"name":"mbrsvc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"hosts":["mbrsvc"],"http":[{"route":[{"destination":{"host":"mbrsvc","subset":"1.0.0"},"weight":100}]}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback) states that the `--timeout` should be in seconds.

> `--timeout`: A value in seconds to wait for Kubernetes commands to complete This defaults to `5m0s`
>
> `--wait`: Waits until all Pods are in a ready state, PVCs are bound, Deployments have minimum (`Desired` minus `maxUnavailable`) Pods in ready state and Services have an IP address (and Ingress if a `LoadBalancer`) before marking the release as successful. It will wait for as long as the `--timeout` value. If timeout is reached, the release will be marked as `FAILED`. Note: In scenario where Deployment has `replicas` set to 1 and `maxUnavailable` is not set to 0 as part of rolling update strategy, `--wait` will return as ready as it has satisfied the minimum Pod in ready condition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried adding seconds. `helm upgrade --install --wait --timeout 10m0s --v 9 mbrsvc ./templateDir/`
It still times out in 30s. I need an option to make API server call wait for longer. The issue is API server call times out in 30s
If I use kubectl and mention `--request-timeout=3m`, API server does not timeout in 30s. How do I reproduce same behavior when I use helm

Comment: I think that `timeout` value should be 600s not 10m. Docs says `value in seconds` 10m is not in seconds.

Comment: ya tried that too. If you see my log output, in the apiserver url, you will not see timeout added. When I use kubectl, it adds timeout to the url. Eg: `curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" 'https://aaaa.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/apis/networking.istio.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/destinationrules?timeout=10m0s '`. I think helm is not honoring the timeout

Comment: If it always times out at 30s then problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This timeout comes from the server (Code 504) not from the client (Helm). Providing a `--timeout` is not going to have an influence here, I'm afraid

Comment: When we give a timeout in kubectl, kubectl adds a query parameter to apiserver call with the timeout value. So -with kubectl- apiserver waits for the specified timeout. Helm should have the same behaviour. But it does not append the timeout query param. Please see my comments for Crou's answer below. It has the logs

Comment: Sorry, I did not read what exactly the question was. I was mistaken to think you expected error shown here (504 Timeout) to disappear if the API call had a higher timeout value. Apologies. I have encountered a similar problem but then, it was some connection issue at a low level which prevented the client to post its payload. Inteestingly, when done on another network, all was working fine

Comment: Also, even a timeout of 1h (my call had one of 20m) is not going to help, as it is an error originating from the API reverse proxy. 504 usually is a proxy timing out waiting for a backend's response. And this particular timeout value is configured in the proxy server's setting, it can't be overridden by a client's API call. Please correct me if I got something wrong